# how do i upgrade ios7 universal app to xcode 6 based universal storyboard app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, ios8

i currently have a xcode 5 (ios 7) based universal app (hence two storyboards) and I am thinking of updating it to ios 8.

Is there a way / best approach to migrate the two storyboards into a universal single storyboard?

I cant see a convert option in xcode 6.

Comment: You can't merge two storyboards in to one universal storyboard. However from file inspector, you can activate size classes and auto layout for a storyboard.

Comment: ok, so once i enable size classes on one storyboard, I guess you are suggesting i copy from the other into it? say only copy the screens that are different (e.g. ipad ones) into the iphone one?

Comment: yes, that or you can still keep both of your storyboards with the new size features.

Comment: Oh,  how do I keep both storyboard with new size features?

Comment: Under general target settings, you should see a segment control below devices dropdown. There you can set individual storyboards both for iPhone and iPad. It doesn't show if you create a new project with Xcode 6 though. You should be all set for your older projects.