# Adding size classes to an existing Xcode project

Tags: ios, storyboard, size-classes

I have an universal application with deployment target 6.1 and above. The application is already in app store. Now I need to make changes as per new requirements and also update it for iOS 8.1. I have two storyboards with auto-layout as "Main_iPhone" and "Main_iPad".

**Question:**
I want to implement size classes now. What are the necessary changes I need to make inside the application or project settings ?

Can I just delete those two storyboards and create a new one and re-design everything or any other better feasible ways are there ?

Note: A detailed bullet steps for necessary changes will be very helpful.
I know auto-layout(Intermediate level). Beginner in case of "Size classes".

Thanks in advance. Happy coding.

Comment: See what u can get from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Comment: @iAnurag Thanks. However in this tutorial it doesn't discuss about "Adding size classes" to an Existing project I guess.

Comment: It look likes a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087401/how-do-i-upgrade-ios7-universal-app-to-xcode-6-based-universal-storyboard-app

Answer (score 0):

There'a no need to delete your storyboards. From the project navigator select the storyboard then in the file inspector in Interface Builder Document section, check "Use Size Classes". Note that the project won't be compatible with Xcode 5 after using Size Classes